# Variable Assigned in try...catch - Scope

Tags: c#, scope, unassigned-variable

I have declared a variable before a try... catch and assigned it in the try block. I keep getting an unassigned variable error for "fileDate".

```
class Something
{
    string fACR = "BAK";
    int numbDays = 5;

    Public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime fileDate;
        try
        {
            fACR = args[0];
            numbDays = int.Parse(args[2]);
            fileDate = DateTime.Parse(args[1]);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS! Follow Format:");
            Console.WriteLine("<farm_acronym> <yyyy-M-d> <# days>");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        inFileName = "U:/CANSO/Engineering/Farms/" + fACR +
            "/DailyDownloads/";
        switch (fACR)
        {
            case "DEM":
                inFileName = inFileName + "Report_Recombiner_" + fileDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + 
                    ".csv";
                break;
            default:
                inFileName = inFileName + "REPORT_Recombiner_" + fileDate.ToString("yyyy-M-d") + 
                    ".csv";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using this while declaring:

```
DateTime fileDate = null;
```

That doesn't work either (DateTime is not nullable). Any suggestions?

Comment: If the exception is caught, you continue anyway. What value of `fileDate` do you want to use if it fails to parse? Or did you mean to insert a `return` into the catch block?

Comment: It's in my main method. Don't need a return. Just want to throw exception if it doesn't parse.

Comment: Your code doesn't throw an exception though, it catches it. If you step through, you'll see that it continues going after the catch block. You should either `return` or `throw` at the end of your catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: If after logging the error to console you need to stop the execution then you can rethrow the exception. But still the code needs more improvements.

Others explained the reason behind the error. But I would suggest you refactor your code and take the try/catch out and write it as a method. But still the following code is not good. I don't like the way `fACR` and `numbDays` are defined.

```
class Something
{
    string fACR = "BAK";
    int numbDays = 5;

    Public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime fileDate = GetFileDate(args);


        inFileName = "U:/CANSO/Engineering/Farms/" + fACR +
            "/DailyDownloads/";
        switch (fACR)
        {
            case "DEM":
                inFileName = inFileName + "Report_Recombiner_" + fileDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + 
                    ".csv";
                break;
            default:
                inFileName = inFileName + "REPORT_Recombiner_" + fileDate.ToString("yyyy-M-d") + 
                    ".csv";
                break;
        }
    }
    public static DateTime GetFileDate(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            fACR = args[0];
            numbDays = int.Parse(args[2]);
            return DateTime.Parse(args[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS! Follow Format:");
            Console.WriteLine("<farm_acronym> <yyyy-M-d> <# days>");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Get an "all paths do not return a value" with the try/catch in the method. Unless I return a dummy DateTime value at the end of the catch. Is that good practice though?

Comment: Don't `throw e;` - just `throw;` - then you don't reset the stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign it some value. As you noted, `DateTime` isn't a reference type, so it can't be null. So just assign it some default value you know is invalid - say, `DateTime.MinValue`. You can later check for that value to see if it was assigned.

Of course, if `DateTime.MinValue` is a *valid* value for you, as are all other values, you should use a more robust way of checking whether an assignment was made - for instance, by using a nullable `DateTime?`. In general it is frowned upon .NET to use special values to mark invalid data - this is precisely what Nullable types are for.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a nullable DateTime, "DateTime?" (this means, explicitly, "a DateTime that also allows for a null value"), or probably easier in this case, just assign your DateTime a flag value when you create it, like `DateTime fileDate = DateTime.MinValue`

Of course, in this case, it seems like you would just want to return in the catch and put fileDate inside the try scope - what good is having the fileDate variable in scope outside the try/catch, if it wasn't initialized properly anyway?